# Dynamic endpoint extension in generic DataService

Tags: angular, rest, web-services

I have a generic DataService with everything needed to request my API. I have several services who extends this DataService in order to request specific endpoints.

I would like to find a way for my generic DataService to know which endpoind it has to request.

At first, i did pass the URL to request in my DataService constructor, i had something like this :

DataService :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from '../common/validators/app-error';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { BadRequest } from './../common/bad-request-error';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private url: string, public httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  getOne(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  create(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  update(ressource,oldRessource){
    return this.httpClient.put(this.url + '/' + oldRessource, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  delete(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  public handleError(err: Response){
    if (err.status == 400 ){
      return Observable.throw(new BadRequest(err));
    }

    if (err.status == 404) {
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
    }
    // Return error by default if no specific error
    return Observable.throw(new AppError(err));
  }
}
```

A service extending from DataService

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategorieService extends DataService {

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) { 

    super('http://localhost:8081/categories' ,httpClient);

  }
}
```

But it gave me this error :

> Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in
>   /ng-app/src/app/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object]).

So I understood I can't put string in constructors in Angular. I heared about Injection Tokens and Environement.ts, so I tried something like that :

App.module.ts :

```
...

import { CategorieService } from './services/categorie.service';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


export function getBaseUrl(): string {
  return environment.API_BASE_URL;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    DataService,
    CategorieService,
    { provide: 'API_BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Environement.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_BASE_URL: "http://localhost:8081/",
};
```

Data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from '../common/validators/app-error';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { BadRequest } from './../common/bad-request-error';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  //constructor(private url: string, public httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  constructor(@Inject('API_BASE_URL') private url, public httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  getOne(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  create(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  update(ressource,oldRessource){
    return this.httpClient.put(this.url + '/' + oldRessource, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  delete(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  public handleError(err: Response){
    if (err.status == 400 ){
      return Observable.throw(new BadRequest(err));
    }

    if (err.status == 404) {
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
    }
    // Return error by default if no specific error
    return Observable.throw(new AppError(err));
  }
}
```

But I still don't know how i can change that URL in my DataService for each Services extending from DataService the way i was doing it with the string in constructor. I would like to add some parameters to my base API URL the same way i tried to do it before to be able to reach specific parts of my API but i don't get how to do that with TokenInjection.

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible to not have `DataService` be an actual angular service and just be the base class for all your service classes like `Categorie`, etc. This way you'd be able to call `super('http://localhost:8081/categories' ,httpClient)`. And with the httpClient, you could negate that and just instantiate that in the base class.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from '../common/validators/app-error';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { BadRequest } from './../common/bad-request-error';

export class DataService {
  constructor(private url: string, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAll(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  getOne(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  create(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  update(ressource,oldRessource){
    return this.httpClient.put(this.url + '/' + oldRessource, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  delete(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  public handleError(err: Response){
    if (err.status == 400 ){
      return Observable.throw(new BadRequest(err));
    }

    if (err.status == 404) {
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
    }
    // Return error by default if no specific error
    return Observable.throw(new AppError(err));
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems a good idea but I get this error :

Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
An argument for 'handler' was not provided.

Seems it needs an argument for HttpClient constructor.

Comment: @Ishiru in that event you could revert back to how you were, by pass the httpclient through the child class. `super('http://localhost:8081/categories' ,httpClient)` and inject the httpClient in the child classes. I've updated my answer to reflect that.